# The shell design zendframework

Tags: php, shell, zend-framework, twitter-bootstrap

I 'm facing a problem with my implementation of my shell .
The first public folders I have created . Then wrote the following code skin.xml .

```
enter code here
    <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <skin>
    <stylesheets>
    <stylesheet> layout.css </ stylesheet>
    <stylesheet> text.css </ stylesheet>
    </ stylesheets>
    </ skin>
```

And so I wrote the CSS file and folder
application -> views-> helper file named LoadSkin.php I wrote this code inside

```
enter code here
    <? php
    / **
    * This class loads the cms skin
    *
    * /
    class Zend_View_Helper_LoadSkin extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
    {
    public function loadSkin ($ skin)
    {
    / / Load the skin config file
    $ skinData = new Zend_Config_Xml ('. / skins /'. $ skin. '/ skin.xml');
    $ stylesheets = $ skinData-> stylesheets-> stylesheet-> toArray ();
    / / Append each stylesheet
    if (is_array ($ stylesheets)) {
    foreach ($ stylesheets as $ stylesheet) {
    $ this-> view-> headLink () -> appendStylesheet ('/ skins /'. $ skin.
    '/ css /'. $ stylesheet);
    {
    {
    {
    {
```

I put the following code in bootstrap.php file .

```
enter code here
    protected function _initView ()
    {
    / / Initialize view
    $ view = new Zend_View ();
    $ view-> doctype ('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $ view-> headTitle ('Zend CMS');
    $ view-> skin = 'blues';
    / / Add it to the ViewRenderer
    $ viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker :: getStaticHelper (
    'ViewRenderer'
    ) ;
    $ viewRenderer-> setView ($ view);
    / / Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
    return $ view;
    {
```

In the following code I layout.phtml file .

```
enter code here
    $ this-> loadSkin ($ this-> skin);
```

However when I test the project does not work . Enter the text displayed by the shell without any error but not displayed .
What is the reason ?

I am using the book
Pro
Zend Framework
Techniques
Build a Full CMS Project
(Forrest Lyman)
This book uses the zf1 or zf2?
I did not have any previous experience in this field.

Comment: I would advise against adding your own code in the Zend_ namespace.

Comment: In your layout.phtml file are you echoing headlink `echo $this->headLink();` after your loadSkin call?

Comment: yes echo $this->headLink();is after it.